# Headphone mic only works when the headphone cord moves

Tags: microphone, headphones

My headphone mic stopped working. Naturally I entered "Recording devices" (Win7) to check whats wrong. When I speak into the mic there are no bars that say it is working. But when I move the cord around the bars are moving.

Anyone knows what it means?

Answer (score 4):

It means either the cable is broken inside, or that the contacts are bent in the socket.
Test another headset & another socket to narrow down which is at fault..